# Reversing/mirroring special characters in Python

Tags: python, string, reverse

I'd like to reverse/mirror special characters in Python.

Let's say my string is 'hello (one) sun {apple}'
My output string would have to be '{elppa} nus (eno) olleh'

Of course, with typical reversing, the outcome is '}elppa{ nus )eno( olleh' which is not what I need.

Is there any "easy" way to do this? Using regex, maybe?

Comment: I don't see a relation to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

So, basically you want the braces encapsulating the text to remain same and mirror everything else? In that case you can run a function after mirroring to revert all the braces. The easiest way would be to run the replace subroutine, like below:

```
line = line.replace('<', '!@!@')
line = line.replace('>', '<')
line = line.replace('!@!@', '>')
```

Here I am taking <> as an example, I replace '<' with '!@!@' temporarily, then replace '>' with '<', and then substitute '!@!@' with '>'.

Not a very robust method, but an easy quick fix.

Comment: Yep, I'm currently doing something like that (I have a dictionary and use a function to 'filter' special characters, returning the mirrored char) but maybe there was any built-in method or any other way to do it. Thanks!